# Should the OTP tag be made less ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I propose that [otp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otp) should be replaced with [one-time-passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-passwords) and [one-time-pads](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-pads). The reason for this is that there are two common interpretations of the acronym OTP in security, [one time passwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) and [one time pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

Comment: I agree. Are all the q's in that tag currently referring to pads or passwords?

Comment: @AviD With the exception of: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/idea-safety-data-exchange-with-otps it appears that all the questions are referring to passwords.

Comment: Status: Completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-time pads:

- [Why is using a pseudo-random key considered more practical than a one-time pad?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12733/why-using-a-pseudo-random-key-is-considered-to-be-more-practical)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36757/idea-safety-data-exchange-with-otps

One-time passwords:

- [Mobile OTP - Secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/mobile-otp-secure)
- [Please explain Time-step in Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12652/please-explain-time-step-in-time-based-one-time-password-algorithm)
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14110/number-of-time-steps-in-totp
- [What's the use of adding a challenge to a one time password algorithm?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/whats-the-use-of-adding-a-challenge-to-a-one-time-password-algorithm)
- [How to detect suspicious tokens collected by a hacker](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16301/how-to-detect-suspicious-tokens-collected-by-a-hacker)
- [Why would it be a good idea for someone to get a YubiKey?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17921/why-would-it-be-a-good-idea-for-someone-to-get-or-not-to-get-a-yubi-key)
- [Replacement for One Time Passwords (OTP)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18410/replacement-for-one-time-passwords-otp)
- [SMS Authentication: random OTP or a cryptographic one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/sms-authentication-random-otp-or-a-cryptographic-one)
- [How to store OTP seed securely at the validating server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/how-to-store-otp-seed-securely-at-the-validating-server)
- [What are the main weaknesses of mobile software based OTP generators?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/what-are-the-main-weaknesses-of-mobile-software-based-otp-generators)
- [Is Dual Factor possible during boot with whole disk encryption on Mac FileVault 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24934/is-dual-factor-possible-during-boot-with-whole-disk-encryption-on-mac-filevault)
- [Can I use hardware token OTP to stop piracy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26559/can-i-use-hardware-token-otp-to-stop-piracy)
- [Security evaluation of Vasco's Digipass Mobile SDK for OTP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29946/security-evaluation-of-vascos-digipass-mobile-sdk-for-otp)
- [What is the risk and mitigation of accidentally typing a YubiKey password in an open forum?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30891/what-is-the-risk-and-mitigation-of-accidentally-typing-a-yubikey-password-in-an)
- [What is more secure for voice and SMS OTP: A random number or generated similar to HOTP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31338/what-is-more-secure-for-voice-and-sms-otp-a-random-number-or-generated-similar)
- [HOTP with as HMAC hashing algoritme a hash from the SHA-2 family](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33123/hotp-with-as-hmac-hashing-algoritme-a-hash-from-the-sha-2-family)
- [Client code tampering detection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34257/client-code-tampering-detection)
- [What manufacturers create OATH HOTP cards now that InCard Technologies is no longer in business?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34731/what-manufacturers-create-oath-hotp-cards-now-that-incard-technologies-is-no-lon)

Conclusion: 90% of the use of [otp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otp) is about one-time passwords, so create the tags [one-time-pad](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-pad) and [one-time-password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-password) and make [otp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otp) a synonym of [one-time-password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-password).

I've retagged the two pad questions. Let a mod please create and merge the synonym [otp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otp) → [one-time-password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-time-password).

Comment: +1 Creating a synonym would be the right thing. Replacing/removing will not solve the problem because somebody will create it again